# When is the case to disable database using?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I followed [pr2_tabletop_manipulation_apps/Tutorials/Starting the Manipulation Pipeline](http://ros.org/wiki/pr2_tabletop_manipulation_apps/Tutorials/Starting%20the%20Manipulation%20Pipeline)

It says

"disable database use altogether. In this case, this part of the launch file can be absent. See details below in the Sensor Processing section for disabling database use throughout the pipeline. "

I'm not understand when should disable to use database.

Thank you~

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/36961/when-is-the-case-to-disable-database-using?/) by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2570 on 2012-06-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

To use the database you need to have one. Either you need to set it up locally, which is work or you use Willow's that needs an internet connection. If you don't need the database, you can thus disable it and not worry about that.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2012-06-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0